# firebase DB initialized multiple times. Make sure the format of the database URL matches with each db call

Tags: firebase, security, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I am getting this error while loading the firebase database.

I have deleted the data while I am fixing another issue, Expo Go stopping. my firebase database expires in a day, I have changed the rules to make it work

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false
    }
  }
}



const onSignIn =(googleUser) => {
        console.log('Google Auth Response', googleUser);
        // We need to register an Observer on Firebase Auth to make sure auth is initialized.

        const unsubscribe = firebase
            .auth()
            .onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
            unsubscribe();
            // Check if we are already signed-in Firebase with the correct user.
                if (!isUserEqual(googleUser, firebaseUser)) {
                // Build Firebase credential with the Google ID token.
                    const credential = firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(
                        googleUser.idToken,
                        googleUser.accessToken,
                    );
                    console.log('I am here lately!');
                    // Sign in with credential from the Google user.
       //In debugging my code the next auth line is breaking the execution
firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((result) => {
                            console.log("user signed in !!")
                            if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                                firebase
                                    .database()
                                    .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
                                    .set({
                                        gmail: result.user.email,
                                        profile_picture: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.picture,
                                        first_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.given_name,
                                        last_name: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.family_name,
                                        created_at: Date.now(),
                                    }).then(response => console.log("user info set!"));} else { firebase.database()
                               .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
                                .update({
                                      `enter code here`last_logged_in: Date.now()
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            console.log("Error in Signinig into firebase", error)});
                } else {
                    console.log('User already signed-in Firebase.');
                } })
    }
```

Can anyone help me out to make my firebase database work normally? I got stuck here and unable to develop further after logging in screens in my app.

The following is the issue for me, but I have changed the rules set within 24 hours, will it be effective after 24 hours??

24 hours after changing the rules is completed but my issue is not solved. the app is crashing suddenly while login. Please help me out.

Comment: The error message in your title seems unrelated to the security rules. To help with the error message in the title, we'll need to see the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I got struck here while login with google firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(credential).then((result) => {
                            console.log("user signed in !!")
                            if (result.additionalUserInfo.isNewUser) {
                                firebase
                                    .database()
                                    .ref('/users/' + result.user.uid)
                                    .set({
                                        gmail: result.user.email,}) }

Comment: Please don't post the code in comments. Instead edit your question to have a minimal repro, after studying the link I shared above. Following the guidance in that article drastically increasses the chances that someone can help.

Comment: I have resolved the issue, After updating my rules it took 24 hours for effective changes. That's all.